# Can't set screen resolution for Linux remote session

Tags: freerdp

host: Windows 10

remote: archlinux

In Windows:

$ wfreerdp.exe /v:... /u:... /p:... /size:1920x1080 /floatbar /f

(This is FreeRDP version 2.0.0-dev5 (00eabb2))

Remote session opens with (i think) size 1366x768. Scaled to 1920x1080 (my notebook native resolution), and is very blury.
If I open that session with Microsoft Remote Desktop then screen resolution will be 1920x1080.

I expect that session will be with 1920x1080 screen resolution.